# What's wrong with Windows bat recursion?

Tags: batch-file, recursion, command-line, cmd, echo

I am trying to write Windows batch commands. Here is my test function:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo hi

call :minus 1
echo %result%
call :minus 2
echo %result%
call :minus 3
echo %result%
call :minus 4
echo %result%
call :minus 5
echo %result%

PAUSE
goto :eof

:minus
setlocal

set num=%1
if %num% equ 1 endlocal & set result=%num% & goto :eof

set /a num=%num%-1
call :minus %num%

endlocal
goto :eof
```

As expected, for everything greater than and equal to 1, the result will be 1:

```
hi
1
1
1
1
1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But when I change the first call to `call :minus 2` (the rest is the same):

```
echo hi

call :minus 2
echo %result%
call :minus 2
echo %result%
call :minus 3
echo %result%
call :minus 4
echo %result%
call :minus 5
echo %result%

PAUSE
goto :eof
```

The output is:

```
hi
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What does `ECHO is off.` mean?

Comment: Is the second example your entire script? Or is there more?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Yes the rest of the script is the same. Question is updated. Hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you call `minus` with 2, `result` will never be set (the `if %num% equ 1` won't evaluate to true), hence you call `echo` without any parameter, which will result in `ECHO is off.` as output due to the `@echo off` at the top of your script.

Comment: For `call :minus 2`, I expect the `if ...` line is false. Then the following lines will be run. `%num%` will be decreased by 1, then `call :minus 1`. Isn't it?

Comment: Oh, haven't seen that one. That's indeed strange. I will try to find the error

Comment: Thanks for telling me `ECHO is off` means variable undefined. I have solved it. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `endlocal` at the end. After changing to the same line, ending the local scope before calling the recursive, it runs fine now:

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo hi

call :minus 1
echo %result%
call :minus 2
echo %result%
call :minus 3
echo %result%
call :minus 4
echo %result%
call :minus 5
echo %result%

PAUSE
goto :eof

:minus
setlocal

set num=%1
if %num% equ 1 endlocal & set result=%num% & goto :eof

set /a num=%num%-1
endlocal & call :minus %num%

goto :eof
```

Comment: Nice find, didn't see that. My solution was creating a separate loop to prevent `set num=%1`  from overriding the %num%-1, but this is much easier. (+1)

Comment: Do you mean using loop instead of recursion?

Comment: Somewhat, not exactly sure what i did, but it worked :P. Anyways glad to see you got what you were looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues going on there. The easy way to see what is going on is to put an echo statement ECHO(%~1 at the beginning of the :minus subroutine. Then you will see that you are in trouble because you have a SETLOCAL statement in a recursive subroutine. In short... you are executing SETLOCAL once for each recursion, but only executing ENDLOCAL once for the initial call.

In your case the easiest fix is to get rid of ALL of the setlocal and endlocal statements. I would move the echo into the subroutine instead of repeating it for each call.

BTW, you don't need to EnableDelayedExpansion with your implementation.

It is best to ECHO(%Variable% instead of ECHO %Variable%. The reason is that if the variable is undefined the ECHO statement is the same as simply typing ECHO. Try that... it displays the echo state (on or off). A lot of people use ECHO. or ECHO:  You can read all about it here http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1900